# Please, help. nginx don't serve files with "?" symbol. Need some vhost correction

Tags: nginx

I have some static files on server, which looks like this: jquery.timeentry.css?P
Im getting an 404 error from nginx.
Guys, please help to resolve it.

Comment: If you study a little bit about URL, you will learn that `?` as a reserved character needs to be escaped if it appears in part of the file names, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding This applies to all web servers, not just nginx.

Comment: Reconsider using special symbols in filenames. This (using them) is call for troubles.